# Принудительно удалить приложения через свое приложение

Tags: java, android

Как удалить принудительно приложение а то и несколько приложений через свое приложение?

В Стеке нашел метод удаления по одному, но там нужно чтобы пользователь подтвердил операцию удаления, есть ли метод без подтверждения? Например если взять какие то разрешения от пользователя 1 раз, чтобы потом не спрашивать.

Comment: боюсь сия миссия невозможна)

Comment: Вообще желание выглядит враждебным по отношению к пользователю. Если бы такое было возможно, любая программа прежде всего удаляла бы конкурирующие программы.

Comment: @VladD так то да, но говорю же взять 1 раз разрешение на проведение подобных операций у пользователя, нет такого?

Comment: @VladD а как можно это сделать на устройстве где есть рут? И условие есть ли рут на устройстве или нет

Comment: @Iman: Наверняка можно, но я не знаю, как. Это ж не официальная фича.